# wordpress 404.php page not loading enqueued scripts

Tags: php, wordpress, underscores-wp

first time asking for help online.

I’m trying to use js for some animations on my wordpress 404.php page, but the page doesn’t load the enqueued scripts. I can’t seem to find anything about it in the doc.

the console only tells me ‘Uncaught ReferenceError: anime is not defined’ (anime being part of the enqueued scripts)
none of the enqueued scripts of my theme (from functions.php) are loaded, only on 404.php
The theme is based on underscores, if it's relevant. (_s)

My best guess is i'm not aware of something simple like wordpress or my theme not doing the `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'example_scripts' );` part...

does anyone know what the issue may be ?

Comment: Can you add some more details about your theme?  Like what theme are you using ? any plugins?  Are you adding the `anime` js  yourself?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example